# Yii2 cookie based login

Tags: php, yii2

I was wondering if anyone could explain how the cookie based login works in Yii2. I see the `loginByCookie` method in yii\web\user but I am confused on what file and method actually call it to log the user in? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You don't call the `loginByCookie`-function, it's automatically called for you. 
You initially login the user by calling `\Yii::$app->login()` with an identity, whilst having [`User::$enableAutoLogin`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-user.html#%24enableAutoLogin-detail) enabled. The duration is used to determine the cookies TTL. The framework takes care of the cookie.

For an example, just check out the [`LoginForm`](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-basic/blob/master/models/LoginForm.php)-class in the basic application.